# Endless loop with rand() function beacuse of a mutator c++

Tags: c++, c++11

I have a class Student with a private member that represents a flag. I also have a flag setter function.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>


using namespace std;

class Student
{
private:
    string name;
    int flag;
public:
    Student(const string stname)
    :name(stname),flag(0)
    {
        cout << "Student with name " << name << " has been constructed!" << endl;
    };
    ~Student()
    {
        cout << "Student with name " << name << " to be destroyed!" << endl;
    };
    int get_flag();
    void set_flag(const int number);
};
```

Here are the functions:

```
void Student::set_flag(const int number){  flag = number;}

int Student::get_flag(){  return flag;}
```

What i'm trying to do in main is choose a random number to represent the amount of loops and another random number that chooses which of the student objects flags are to be changed.

The code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string name;
    Student* students[44];
    for(int i=0; i<44; i++)
    {
       cin >> name;
       students[i] = new Student(name);
    }

   int how_many , which;
   srand (time(NULL));
                                //0-44 students can be changed
   how_many = rand() % 44 + 1; //how many students are going to be changed
   int j=1;
   while(j <= how_many) //which students are going to be changed
   {
       //i have 44 students so students array indexes range 0-43
       which = rand() % 43;
       if((students[which])->get_flag() == 1) continue;
       //if the student is not already picked to be changed
       if((students[which])->get_flag() != 1)
       {
          (students[which])->set_flag(1);
          j++;
        }
   }


    for(int i=0; i<44; i++) delete students[i];
}
```

Why does this result to an endless loop. Genuinely curious. It really looks like i'm doing nothing wrong.

Comment: `rand()` is not a good quality generator - it tends to exhibit bias.   `rand() % 43` is not guaranteed to hit every value between 0 and 42 inclusive within a specified time interval.   Depending on how biased it is,  some values may never be hit.     Rather than calculating `rand() % 43` in the (possibly forlorn) hope that it will eventually yield every value between `0` and `42`, generate a vector/array with all values in that range, shuffle it (e.g. using `std::shuffle()` since C++11), and draw shuffled values one at a time.   Even with that, `j` is only incremented at most 43 times not 44

Comment: Don't use ```rand()``` and ```srand()```. Instead, use ```#include <random>``` and ```std::mt19937```

Answer (score 5):

The line

```
how_many = rand() % 44 + 1;
```

will set `how_many` to `44` in the maximum case.

The line

```
which = rand() % 43;
```

will set `which` to one of the 43 numbers between 0 and 42 (both inclusive).

There are only 43 students to have their `flag` set, so `j` is incremented at most 43 times and it will be only at most 44.

When `how_many` is set to `44`, this means the condition `j <= how_many` will never be false and the loop will run endlessly.

It seems the line `which = rand() % 43;` should be `which = rand() % 44;`.

Comment: Hey! thanks for the notice. That would explain part of the problem. Your solution didn't solve the issue though

Answer (score 0):

Even if limit is fixed, you will have more and more difficulties to find an not flagged students

As alternative, you might shuffle the students (or indexes) and flags the first ones.

```
int main()
{
    std::vector<Student> students;
    for (int i = 0; i != 44; i++)
    {
        std::string name;
        std::cin >> name;
        students.emplace_back(name);
    }

    std::random_device rdev; // For random seed
    std::default_random_engine rnd(rdev());

    std::vector<std::size_t> indexes(students.size());
    std::iota(indexes.begin(), indexes.end(), 0); // {0, 1, 2, .., 43}
    std::shuffle(indexes.begin(), indexes.end(), rnd);

    indexes.resize(std::uniform_int_distribution<int>(1, students.size() - 1)(rnd));

    for (std::size_t i : indexes) {
        students[i].set_flag(1);
    }
    // ...
}
```